# Google Cloud Platform project requests and errors

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

The project overview of Google Cloud Platform shows the number of requests/errors within the last 24 hours.

A project with a high number of errors have gotten me concerned, and I want to investigate and understand the reasons for this.

I have been unable to find any documentation or hints in the interface itself.

Does anyone know where to find more info?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to investigate more the issue, you can open a ticket with the Google Cloud Platform Support team "https://cloud.google.com/support/". You can submit your inquiry to them and they will look into it.

Or alternatively "if no support package found", you can post your question(s) in the Google Public Issue Tracker (PIT): "https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/FilingIssues?tm=3" and it will be traced and handled by the Google support team.

In both cases, they are going to give you the answers, best recommendations and even the workaround(s) if found to have your issue resolved.